# com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Table 'apimgt.IDN_CLAIM_DIALECT' doesn't exist

Tags: wso2-api-manager, wso2, wso2-identity-server

I am migrating WSO2 idenity server from IS 5.2.0 --> 5.3.0 with the help of the documentation ,https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS530/Upgrading+from+a+Previous+Release#UpgradingfromaPreviousRelease-step11

While i run the wso2 migration , I am getting the following exception

```
Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Table 'apimgt.IDN_CLAIM_DIALECT' doesn't exist
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
```

Comment: You may be missing some steps or maybe issue in upgrade script. You need to create table 'apimgt.IDN_CLAIM_DIALECT'

Comment: that doesnt help much

Comment: IDN_CLAIM_DIALECT table is created from migration client. So if you are seeing this error, this can be due to not running the migration scripts properly. As per your other question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50186740/wso2-sh-wso2server-sh-dmigrate-dcomponent-identity-is-not-running-the-migratio , were u able to run the migration correctly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

missing org.wso2.carbon.is.migrate.client-5.3.0.jar in the dropins folder was the issue. Once copied the org.wso2.carbon.is.migrate.client-5.3.0.jar to dropins, the issue got solved.