# WSO2 sh wso2server.sh -Dmigrate -Dcomponent=identity is not running the migration scripts

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

I am migrating WSO2 Idenitity server as per https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS530/Upgrading+from+a+Previous+Release
I copied the scripts to wso2is-km-5.3.0/dbscripts/identity/migration-5.2.0_to_5.3.0 folder.

But after running sh wso2server.sh -Dmigrate -Dcomponent=identity , it doesnt look like its running the scripts.None of the new tables are getting created.

Any clue?

```
    [ec2-user@ip-171-30-1-7 bin]$ sh wso2server.sh -Dmigrate -Dcomponent=identity
JAVA_HOME environment variable is set to /usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.8.0_121
CARBON_HOME environment variable is set to /home/ec2-user/wso2qa2/wso2is/wso2is-                                                                                        km-5.3.0
Using Java memory options: -Xms256m -Xmx1024m
[2018-05-06 14:01:25,761]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.core.internal.CarbonCoreActivator} -  Starting WSO2 Carbon...
[2018-05-06 14:01:25,761]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.core.internal.CarbonCoreActivator} -  Operating System : Linux 4.14.33-51.34.amzn1.x86_64, amd64
[2018-05-06 14:01:25,762]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.core.internal.CarbonCoreActivator} -  Java Home        : /usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.8.0_121/jre
[2018-05-06 14:01:25,762]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.core.internal.CarbonCoreActivator} -  Java Version     : 1.8.0_121
[2018-05-06 14:01:25,762]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.core.internal.CarbonCoreActivator} -  Java VM          : Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM 25.121-b13,Oracle Corporation
[2018-05-06 14:01:25,762]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.core.internal.CarbonCoreActivator} -  Carbon Home      : /home/ec2-user/wso2qa2/wso2is/wso2is-km-5.3.0
[2018-05-06 14:01:25,762]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.core.internal.CarbonCoreActivator} -  Java Temp Dir    : /home/ec2-user/wso2qa2/wso2is/wso2is-km-5.3.0/tmp
[2018-05-06 14:01:25,762]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.core.internal.CarbonCoreActivator} -  User             : ec2-user, en-US, Etc/UTC
[2018-05-06 14:01:25,850]  WARN {org.wso2.carbon.core.bootup.validator.util.ValidationResultPrinter} -  Swap Memory size (MB): 0 of the system is below the recommended minimum size :2047
[2018-05-06 14:01:25,907]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.event.output.adapter.kafka.internal.ds.KafkaEventAdapterServiceDS} -  Successfully deployed the Kafka output event adaptor service
[2018-05-06 14:01:25,948]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.event.processor.manager.core.internal.util.ManagementModeConfigurationLoader} -  CEP started in Single node mode
[2018-05-06 14:01:26,336]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.ldap.server.configuration.LDAPConfigurationBuilder} -  KDC server is disabled.
[2018-05-06 14:01:27,866]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.mex.internal.Office365SupportMexComponent} -  Office365Support MexServiceComponent bundle activated successfully..
[2018-05-06 14:01:27,871]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.mex2.internal.DynamicCRMCustomMexComponent} -  DynamicCRMSupport MexServiceComponent bundle activated successfully.
[2018-05-06 14:01:28,432]  WARN {org.wso2.carbon.user.core.config.RealmConfigXMLProcessor} -  Required property DomainName missing in secondary user store. Skip adding the user store.
[2018-05-06 14:01:35,934]  INFO {org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule} -  TLD skipped. URI: http://tiles.apache.org/tags-tiles is already defined
[2018-05-06 14:01:36,144]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.jdbc.EmbeddedRegistryService} -  Configured Registry in 50ms
[2018-05-06 14:01:36,161]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.identity.authenticator.x509Certificate.internal.X509CertificateServiceComponent} -  X509 Certificate Servlet activated successfully..
[2018-05-06 14:01:36,266]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.jdbc.EmbeddedRegistryService} -  Connected to mount at govregistry in 71ms
[2018-05-06 14:01:41,083]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.jdbc.EmbeddedRegistryService} -  Connected to mount at govregistry in 142ms
[2018-05-06 14:01:42,155]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.internal.RegistryCoreServiceComponent} -  Registry Mode    : READ-WRITE
[2018-05-06 14:01:42,594]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.attachment.mgt.server.internal.AttachmentServiceComponent} -  Initialising Attachment Server
[2018-05-06 14:01:42,800]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.attachment.mgt.core.dao.impl.jpa.AbstractJPAVendorAdapter} -  [Attachment-Mgt OpenJPA] DB Dictionary: h2
[2018-05-06 14:01:42,800]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.attachment.mgt.core.dao.impl.jpa.AbstractJPAVendorAdapter} -  [Attachment-Mgt OpenJPA] Generate DDL Enabled.
[2018-05-06 14:01:43,262]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.attachment.mgt.server.internal.AttachmentServiceComponent} -  Registering AttachmentServerService
[2018-05-06 14:01:43,269]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.bpel.core.internal.BPELServiceComponent} -  Initializing BPEL Engine........
[2018-05-06 14:01:43,299]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.bpel.core.ode.integration.BPELServerImpl} -  Using DAO Connection Factory class: org.apache.ode.dao.jpa.BPELDAOConnectionFactoryImpl
[2018-05-06 14:01:43,407]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.bpel.core.ode.integration.BPELServerImpl} -  Registering E4X Extension...
[2018-05-06 14:01:43,409]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.bpel.core.ode.integration.BPELServerImpl} -  Registering B4P Extension...
[2018-05-06 14:01:43,411]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.bpel.core.ode.integration.BPELServerImpl} -  Registering B4P Filter...
[2018-05-06 14:01:43,415]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.bpel.core.ode.integration.BPELServerImpl} -  Registering MBeans
[2018-05-06 14:01:43,439]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.humantask.core.internal.HumanTaskServiceComponent} -  Initialising HumanTask Server
[2018-05-06 14:01:43,459]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.humantask.core.dao.jpa.AbstractJPAVendorAdapter} -  [HT OpenJPA] DB Dictionary: h2
[2018-05-06 14:01:43,460]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.humantask.core.dao.jpa.AbstractJPAVendorAdapter} -  [HT OpenJPA] Generate DDL Enabled.
[2018-05-06 14:01:43,479]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.humantask.core.internal.HumanTaskServiceComponent} -  Registering Axis2ConfigurationContextObserver
[2018-05-06 14:01:43,483]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.humantask.core.internal.HumanTaskServiceComponent} -  Registering HT related MBeans
[2018-05-06 14:01:43,487]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.humantask.core.internal.HumanTaskServiceComponent} -  MXBean for Human tasks registered successfully
[2018-05-06 14:01:43,547]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.metrics.impl.util.JmxReporterBuilder} -  Creating JMX reporter for Metrics with domain 'org.wso2.carbon.metrics'
[2018-05-06 14:01:43,550]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.metrics.impl.util.JDBCReporterBuilder} -  Creating JDBC reporter for Metrics with source 'ip-172-31-2-70.us-east-2.compute.internal', data source 'jdbc/WSO2MetricsDB' and 60 seconds polling period
[2018-05-06 14:01:43,555]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.metrics.impl.reporter.AbstractReporter} -  Started JDBC reporter for Metrics
[2018-05-06 14:01:43,555]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.metrics.impl.reporter.AbstractReporter} -  Started JMX reporter for Metrics
[2018-05-06 14:01:44,587]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.registry.indexing.solr.SolrClient} -  Default Embedded Solr Server Initialized
[2018-05-06 14:01:49,723]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.user.core.internal.UserStoreMgtDSComponent} -  Carbon UserStoreMgtDSComponent activated successfully.
[2018-05-06 14:02:02,926]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.identity.user.store.configuration.deployer.UserStoreConfigurationDeployer} -  User Store Configuration Deployer initiated.
[2018-05-06 14:02:02,927]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.identity.user.store.configuration.deployer.UserStoreConfigurationDeployer} -  User Store Configuration Deployer initiated.
[2018-05-06 14:02:02,932]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.bpel.deployer.BPELDeployer} -  Initializing BPEL Deployer for tenant -1234.
[2018-05-06 14:02:02,939]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.humantask.deployer.HumanTaskDeployer} -  Initializing HumanTask Deployer for tenant -1234.
[2018-05-06 14:02:07,269]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.core.deployment.DeploymentInterceptor} -  Deploying Axis2 service: I18nEmailMgtConfigService {super-tenant}
[2018-05-06 14:02:09,128]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.core.deployment.DeploymentInterceptor} -  Deploying Axis2 service: AccountCredentialMgtConfigService {super-tenant}
[2018-05-06 14:02:09,533]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.core.deployment.DeploymentInterceptor} -  Deploying Axis2 service: UserIdentityManagementAdminService {super-tenant}
[2018-05-06 14:02:09,938]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.core.deployment.DeploymentInterceptor} -  Deploying Axis2 service: UserInformationRecoveryService {super-tenant}
[2018-05-06 14:02:10,521]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.core.deployment.DeploymentInterceptor} -  Deploying Axis2 service: SAMLQueryService {super-tenant}
[2018-05-06 14:02:11,490]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.core.deployment.DeploymentInterceptor} -  Deploying Axis2 service: mex-ut {super-tenant}
[2018-05-06 14:02:11,897]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.core.deployment.DeploymentInterceptor} -  Deploying Axis2 service: mex-ut2 {super-tenant}
[2018-05-06 14:02:12,535]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.core.deployment.DeploymentInterceptor} -  Deploying Axis2 service: wso2carbon-sts {super-tenant}
[2018-05-06 14:02:15,136]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.core.init.CarbonServerManager} -  Repository       : /home/ec2-user/wso2qa2/wso2is/wso2is-km-5.3.0/repository/deployment/server/
[2018-05-06 14:02:15,152]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.internal.APIManagerComponent} -  No RXTs Found.
[2018-05-06 14:02:15,153]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.internal.APIManagerComponent} -  Default tier policies not found in : /home/ec2-user/wso2qa2/wso2is/wso2is-km-5.3.0/repository/resources/default-tiers/default-tiers.xml
[2018-05-06 14:02:15,153]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.internal.APIManagerComponent} -  Default tier policies not found in : /home/ec2-user/wso2qa2/wso2is/wso2is-km-5.3.0/repository/resources/default-tiers/default-app-tiers.xml
[2018-05-06 14:02:15,153]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.internal.APIManagerComponent} -  Default tier policies not found in : /home/ec2-user/wso2qa2/wso2is/wso2is-km-5.3.0/repository/resources/default-tiers/default-res-tiers.xml
[2018-05-06 14:02:17,937]  WARN {org.wso2.carbon.user.core.config.RealmConfigXMLProcessor} -  Required property DomainName missing in secondary user store. Skip adding the user store.
[2018-05-06 14:02:17,942]  WARN {org.wso2.carbon.user.core.config.RealmConfigXMLProcessor} -  Required property DomainName missing in secondary user store. Skip adding the user store.
[2018-05-06 14:02:17,947]  WARN {org.wso2.carbon.user.core.config.RealmConfigXMLProcessor} -  Required property DomainName missing in secondary user store. Skip adding the user store.
[2018-05-06 14:02:18,031]  WARN {org.wso2.carbon.user.core.config.RealmConfigXMLProcessor} -  Required property DomainName missing in secondary user store. Skip adding the user store.
[2018-05-06 14:02:18,033]  WARN {org.wso2.carbon.user.core.config.RealmConfigXMLProcessor} -  Required property DomainName missing in secondary user store. Skip adding the user store.
[2018-05-06 14:02:28,168]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.core.multitenancy.eager.TenantLoadingConfig} -  Using tenant lazy loading policy...
[2018-05-06 14:02:29,820]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.core.internal.permission.update.PermissionUpdater} -  Permission cache updated for tenant -1234
[2018-05-06 14:02:39,807] ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.identity.claim.metadata.mgt.DefaultClaimMetadataStore} -  Error while retrieving claim dialects
org.wso2.carbon.identity.claim.metadata.mgt.exception.ClaimMetadataException: Error while listing claim dialects
        at org.wso2.carbon.identity.claim.metadata.mgt.dao.ClaimDialectDAO.getClaimDialects(ClaimDialectDAO.java:63)
        at org.wso2.carbon.identity.claim.metadata.mgt.DefaultClaimMetadataStore.<init>(DefaultClaimMetadataStore.java:71)
        at org.wso2.carbon.identity.claim.metadata.mgt.ClaimMetadataStoreFactory.createClaimManager(ClaimMetadataStoreFactory.java:54)
        at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.internal.UserStoreMgtDSComponent.setClaimManagerFactory(UserStoreMgtDSComponent.java:131)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.model.ComponentReference.bind(ComponentReference.java:376)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.model.ServiceComponentProp.bindReference(ServiceComponentProp.java:430)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.InstanceProcess.dynamicBind(InstanceProcess.java:416)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.Resolver.getEligible(Resolver.java:334)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.SCRManager.serviceChanged(SCRManager.java:222)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.FilteredServiceListener.serviceChanged(FilteredServiceListener.java:107)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.dispatchEvent(BundleContextImpl.java:861)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:230)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.ListenerQueue.dispatchEventSynchronous(ListenerQueue.java:148)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistry.publishServiceEventPrivileged(ServiceRegistry.java:819)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistry.publishServiceEvent(ServiceRegistry.java:771)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistrationImpl.register(ServiceRegistrationImpl.java:130)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistry.registerService(ServiceRegistry.java:214)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.registerService(BundleContextImpl.java:433)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.registerService(BundleContextImpl.java:451)
        at org.wso2.carbon.identity.claim.metadata.mgt.internal.IdentityClaimManagementServiceComponent.activate(IdentityClaimManagementServiceComponent.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.model.ServiceComponent.activate(ServiceComponent.java:260)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.model.ServiceComponentProp.activate(ServiceComponentProp.java:146)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.model.ServiceComponentProp.build(ServiceComponentProp.java:345)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.InstanceProcess.buildComponent(InstanceProcess.java:620)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.InstanceProcess.buildComponents(InstanceProcess.java:197)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.Resolver.getEligible(Resolver.java:343)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.SCRManager.serviceChanged(SCRManager.java:222)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.FilteredServiceListener.serviceChanged(FilteredServiceListener.java:107)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.dispatchEvent(BundleContextImpl.java:861)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:230)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.ListenerQueue.dispatchEventSynchronous(ListenerQueue.java:148)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistry.publishServiceEventPrivileged(ServiceRegistry.java:819)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistry.publishServiceEvent(ServiceRegistry.java:771)

        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.registerService(BundleContextImpl.java:451)
        at org.wso2.carbon.core.init.CarbonServerManager.initializeCarbon(CarbonServerManager.java:514)
        at org.wso2.carbon.core.init.CarbonServerManager.removePendingItem(CarbonServerManager.java:290)
        at org.wso2.carbon.core.init.PreAxis2ConfigItemListener.bundleChanged(PreAxis2ConfigItemListener.java:118)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.dispatchEvent(BundleContextImpl.java:847)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:230)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager$EventThread.run(EventManager.java:340)
Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Table 'apimgt.IDN_CLAIM_DIALECT' doesn't exist
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:425)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:408)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:943)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3970)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3906)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:2524)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2677)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2549)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeInternal(PreparedStatement.java:1861)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeQuery(PreparedStatement.java:1962)
        at org.wso2.carbon.identity.claim.metadata.mgt.dao.ClaimDialectDAO.getClaimDialects(ClaimDialectDAO.java:55)
        ... 72 more
[2018-05-06 14:02:40,092] ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.identity.claim.metadata.mgt.DefaultClaimMetadataStore} -  Error while retrieving claim dialects
org.wso2.carbon.identity.claim.metadata.mgt.exception.ClaimMetadataException: Error while listing claim dialects
        at org.wso2.carbon.identity.claim.metadata.mgt.dao.ClaimDialectDAO.getClaimDialects(ClaimDialectDAO.java:63)
        at org.wso2.carbon.identity.claim.metadata.mgt.DefaultClaimMetadataStore.<init>(DefaultClaimMetadataStore.java:71)
        at org.wso2.carbon.identity.claim.metadata.mgt.ClaimMetadataStoreFactory.createClaimManager(ClaimMetadataStoreFactory.java:54)
        at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.internal.UserStoreMgtDSComponent.setClaimManagerFactory(UserStoreMgtDSComponent.java:132)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.model.ComponentReference.bind(ComponentReference.java:376)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.model.ServiceComponentProp.bindReference(ServiceComponentProp.java:430)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.InstanceProcess.dynamicBind(InstanceProcess.java:416)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.Resolver.getEligible(Resolver.java:334)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.SCRManager.serviceChanged(SCRManager.java:222)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.FilteredServiceListener.serviceChanged(FilteredServiceListener.java:107)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.dispatchEvent(BundleContextImpl.java:861)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:230)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.ListenerQueue.dispatchEventSynchronous(ListenerQueue.java:148)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistry.publishServiceEventPrivileged(ServiceRegistry.java:819)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistry.publishServiceEvent(ServiceRegistry.java:771)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistrationImpl.register(ServiceRegistrationImpl.java:130)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistry.registerService(ServiceRegistry.java:214)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.registerService(BundleContextImpl.java:433)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.registerService(BundleContextImpl.java:451)
        at org.wso2.carbon.identity.claim.metadata.mgt.internal.IdentityClaimManagementServiceComponent.activate(IdentityClaimManagementServiceComponent.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.model.ServiceComponent.activate(ServiceComponent.java:260)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.model.ServiceComponentProp.activate(ServiceComponentProp.java:146)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.model.ServiceComponentProp.build(ServiceComponentProp.java:345)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.InstanceProcess.buildComponent(InstanceProcess.java:620)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.InstanceProcess.buildComponents(InstanceProcess.java:197)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.Resolver.getEligible(Resolver.java:343)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.SCRManager.serviceChanged(SCRManager.java:222)

        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.registerService(BundleContextImpl.java:451)
        at org.wso2.carbon.identity.core.internal.IdentityCoreServiceComponent.activate(IdentityCoreServiceComponent.java:171)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.model.ServiceComponent.activate(ServiceComponent.java:260)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.model.ServiceComponentProp.activate(ServiceComponentProp.java:146)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.model.ServiceComponentProp.build(ServiceComponentProp.java:345)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.InstanceProcess.buildComponent(InstanceProcess.java:620)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.InstanceProcess.buildComponents(InstanceProcess.java:197)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.Resolver.getEligible(Resolver.java:343)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.SCRManager.serviceChanged(SCRManager.java:222)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.FilteredServiceListener.serviceChanged(FilteredServiceListener.java:107)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.dispatchEvent(BundleContextImpl.java:861)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:230)

        at org.wso2.carbon.core.init.PreAxis2ConfigItemListener.bundleChanged(PreAxis2ConfigItemListener.java:118)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.dispatchEvent(BundleContextImpl.java:847)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:230)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager$EventThread.run(EventManager.java:340)
Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Table 'apimgt.IDN_CLAIM_DIALECT' doesn't exist
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:425)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:408)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:943)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3970)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3906)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:2524)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2677)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2549)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeInternal(PreparedStatement.java:1861)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeQuery(PreparedStatement.java:1962)
        at org.wso2.carbon.identity.claim.metadata.mgt.dao.ClaimDialectDAO.getClaimDialects(ClaimDialectDAO.java:55)
        ... 72 more
[2018-05-06 14:02:40,094]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.user.core.internal.UserStoreMgtDSComponent} -  Claim manager set for class org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.DefaultRealm
[2018-05-06 14:02:40,097]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.user.core.internal.UserStoreMgtDSComponent} -  Claim manager set for class org.wso2.carbon.user.core.jdbc.JDBCUserStoreManager
```

Comment: Did you get any error when migration? Did you get the info log "Migration completed from IS 5.2.0 to IS 5.3.0" while migrating? (You could check it in wso2carbon.log file)

Comment: Nope...I didnt get any errors or migration completed message..
It looks like the parameters are kind of ignored

Comment: Didn't you get any info messages from "org.wso2.carbon.is.migration.client.MigrateFrom520to530" class?.

Comment: No I guess.Cant find anything in the logs at all

Comment: I just ran the sh wso2server.sh -Dmigrate -Dcomponent=identity now again.I cant see any messages like that.I am using the pack wso2is-km-5.3.0 and I downloaded it using download wget --user-agent="testuser" --referer="http://connect.wso2.com/wso2/getform/reg/new_product_download" http://product-dist.wso2.com/downloads/api-manager/2.1.0/identity-server/wso2is-km-5.3.0.zip

Comment: Is it possible to share full logs of one startup by starting the server using sh wso2server.sh -Dmigrate -Dcomponent=identity?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/170478/discussion-between-jocket-and-nilasini).

Comment: attaching the logs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the discussion through the chat, identified that missing org.wso2.carbon.is.migrate.client-5.3.0.jar in the dropins folder was the issue. Once copied the org.wso2.carbon.is.migrate.client-5.3.0.jar to dropins, the issue got solved.